# Modifying HP on spawn for custom boss

Tags: azerothcore

I have created my own custom boss by inserting my own entry into creature_template table. I can spawn the boss just fine and adjust HP and boss attributes as per creature_template settings.

What I really need is to have this custom boss spawn with 50% of its max HP. I've looked through possible GM commands and it looks what I want to do is not possible through existing commands. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want it to always spawn with that percentage, why not just set the default HP to 1/2 its value and be done with it?

Comment: I want to spawn with a fraction of max HP for execution phase testing specifically. Behaviour similar to Vaelastrasz the Corrupt in Blackwing Lair basically (but starting at ~50% instead of ~22%), is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ahh I see, well in the mean time, you could try what I said to test him out and then bump him back up when he is fully tested.  But I get you, if there is a command to pass a percentage hopefully someone has it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found was with a script. Adding a script for the boss and overloading the `Reset()` function (like below) using `ScriptedAI` interface, can set the HP to whatever % you want. However, you need to turn off the health regen in the `creature_template` table for that or the boss will quickly regen to 100% after it's been spawned.

```cpp
void Reset() override
{
    me->SetHealth(me->CountPctFromMaxHealth(40));
}
```

Edit: Please update if there is an easier way/more effective way to this. Thanks!